# Time-delay effect GPUImage

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I'm trying to achieve the "Ghost" effect from http://webcamtoy.com/ using GPUImage.

My understanding is that it would be a two-input filter, with a given time delay between the two frames used. I'd then just add the two frames with 0.5 alpha each.

I've seen how to use the current and previous frames with GPUImage using GPUImageBuffer (example of that in the GPUImageLowPassFilter) but I'm not sure how to set up a time delay between the two frames I want to use.

Any ideas or pointers? I was thinking of creating a custom filter and overriding `newFrameReadyAtTime:atIndex:` to delay the propagation downstream for the first x frames (where x is the delay in terms of number of frames). Maybe a clean way to do this would be to subclass GPUImageBuffer to automatically stack x frames before piping them out into a 2-input filter.

Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't need to subclass GPUImageBuffer to get it to stack frames, just set the bufferSize property to the number of frames you wish to delay by. However, be aware that this will cause a significant increase in memory usage due to each of these additional video frames being buffered. Unfortunately, I don't have Flash on any of my machines right now, so I can't see how this Ghost effect is supposed to operate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Brad and thanks for the great framework! I saw the bufferSize property but by looking through code it didn't seem like it would create a delay automatically but I'll definitely give it a try. Here is a photo taken with that effect https://www.dropbox.com/s/ar1qi9jl6fnzlds/webcam-toy-photo1.jpg. This video is also an example of the end goal (although to start with I'd need one delayed version and not several) http://vimeo.com/35770492.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're on the right track with keeping old frames. For the color effects, you're looking at something like extracting the color channels, using them as input to combine in a blend filter. The key is that the input's values have to add up to the natural color values in the non-changing portions of the video.